# Select text colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu that gives you a choice of names of colors and they should appear in that color. So red should be red, blue should be blue, etc. And I want them to stay the same when you're looking at the list, when hovered over, and when they're selected. So far I've got them appearing correctly in the list and when hovered but not when selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker(); 

  $("#select").selectpicker("refresh");
  $('.filter-option').css("color","green");
});
```

```css
.selectContainer {width:200px}
```

```html
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="select">
    <option value="1" style="color:red">Red</option>
    <option value="2" style="color:blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You can see what I mean here on the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wvj3wx0/).
Can anyone help?

Comment: State your question. What is it you are asking?

Comment: My question is how can I do what I explained. If you look at the JSFiddle you'll see that when you click on the dropdown Red and Blue appear as the correct colors even when hovered over, which is what I want, but when one is selected it doesn't stay the right color.

Comment: Put that explanation within your question not the comments or a jsfiddle. Links go dead and saying, "Look at the fiddle" does no one any good in the future should that go dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$('.filter-option').css("color","green");` by `$('.filter-option').css("color",$('#select').val());`

If you don't mind changing the values to match the color this will do:

```
  $('#select').on('change', function(){
    $('.filter-option').css('color', $(this).val());
  });
```

As in :

```
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="select">
    <option value="red" style="color:red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue" style="color:blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm getting a similar result to the one below.

Comment: That's an improvement, but you still have to click and select one for it to appear the right color. When you load it up it says Red, but it still appears in green. I want it to appear as the correct color in all instances.

Comment: Then why did you put `$('.filter-option').css("color","green");` ? updated my answer too, with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bp01u4tc/2/)

Comment: Oh awesome, you've cracked it. Thanks so much.
I think I just left that in from a previous example.

Answer (score 2):

You can add data attribute with color and check when change so you can add the color to the selected option or you can just use name of class as font color but data attribute is better i think.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  //$(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker(); 

  //$("#select").selectpicker("refresh");
  $('.filter-option').css("color","green");
  
  $(".pickerSelectClass").on('change', function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this), 
    fontColor = $(optionSelected).data('color');
    $(this).css('color', fontColor);
  })
  
  // exemple with class name as font color
  $(".exempleClassName").on('change', function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this), 
    fontColor = $(optionSelected).attr('class');
    $(this).css('color', fontColor);
  })
});
```

```css
.selectContainer { width:200px; }
.pickerSelectClass { color: red; }
.red { color: red; }
.blue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="select">
    <option value="1" class="red" data-color="#FF0000">Red</option>
    <option value="2" class="blue" data-color="#0018FF">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
<h3>Exemple with using class name</h3>
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass exempleClassName" id="select">
    <option value="1" class="red">Red</option>
    <option value="2" class="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks the hover behaviour that I was trying to keep. Now the highlighting is the standard blue background and white text and I want the colors to stay when hovered over. Also, when you first load it up it says Red, but it doesn't appear actually in red until you go in and select.

Comment: Good luck :))))